# Trying to download data.csv from SFTP using R

Tags: r, sftp

I'm a newbie on R. user. 
I am trying to download some files(.csv) from sftp server (with an username and password) to R without passing by an application FileZilla2.

The site explained the method: https://transparency.entsoe.eu/content/static_content/Static%20content/knowledge%20base/SFTP-Transparency_Docs.html

I download an SFTP client software: FileZilla 2. By using this software, with: 
Hostname: sftp-transparency.entsoe.eu;Port:22;User Name: The email address I used;
Password: my password

The aim is to download: 
/TP_export/ActualGenerationOutputPerUnit/2020_5_ActualGenerationOutputPerUnit.csv
to my: 
/Users/macbook/Desktop/

So, what I did:

```
library(curl)
library(RCurl)
url<- "ftp://sftp-transparency.entsoe.eu/TP_export/ActualGenerationOutputPerUnit/2020_5_ActualGenerationOutputPerUnit.csv"
```

I tried sftp//sftp...

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

So I used :

```
url<- "ftp://sftp-transparency.entsoe.eu/TP_export/ActualGenerationOutputPerUnit/2020_5_ActualGenerationOutputPerUnit.csv"
```

after this

```
userpwd <- "identifiant:password"
filenames <- getURI(url = url, userpwd = userpwd, port =22)
filenames <- getBinaryURL(url = url, userpwd = userpwd, port =22)
filenames <- getURL(url = url, userpwd = userpwd, port =22)
filenames <- getURI(url = url, userpwd = userpwd, verbose = TRUE, port = 22)
```

I tried all of the lines but nothing was working

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : response reading failed
```

I am a little bit lost to achieve my goal.

How can I do that ?

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.samuelbosch.com/2018/08/adding-support-for-sftp-to-rcurl.html

Comment: You say you want to use sftp but your url starts with `ftp://`. I just tried (on win10), and with `sftp://` was able to transfer (over ssh-ftp) while `ftp://` failed. Are you able to use `scp` on the command line (outside of R)? (I think @jaksco's comment is still relevant)

Comment: Hi @jaksco, I tried the link you posted but it didn't work. I read also the comments for the link and I have the same issue unfortunately. The only proctocol I have right now is for ftp. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Hi @r2evans, I would like to use ```sftp:// ```but it didn't work. That's why I tried to use  ```ftp:// ```.I don't know what is   ```scp```. Could you explain more please ?

Comment: While they all have FTP in their names, they are very different. FTP is completely in-the-clear, your username and password and all files are completely "clear" for anybody else on the network to see without ambiguity. FTPS is FTP over SSL, considered secure. SFTP is FTP over SSH, also considered secure. Typically SFTP is provided by `sshd`, the SSH daemon; typically FTPS is implemented by the FTP server, linked against openssl or similar. Very different.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @r2evans!